# Applying increment to ternary operator in C

Tags: c, increment, ternary-operator

I thought that the ternary operator returns either a value on the left side or the right side of `:` depending on the condition. Why does this following piece of code print 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int c = 0;
  (c?c:0)++;
  printf("%i", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when this `0++;` is executed? I can't even imagine that this compiles.

Comment: Logic is flawed anyway, you are not printing the value of ternary operator here

Comment: But (c?0:c)++ didn't compile, crazy

Comment: With GCC 4.5.0:  `In function ‘main’:
5:2: error: lvalue required as increment operand` What is returned when you compile this code with `gcc -S code.cpp`?

Comment: For whatever reason it only happens with `0`... at least on my gcc 4.4.3, for everything else it doesn't allow it to compile. Seems like a bug.

Comment: For single char output, instead of `#include <stdio.h>` and printf use putchar(c+'0')

Comment: Is it being compiled as C or C++?  gcc will automatically switch between them based on the filename, remember, and C++ allows ?: to evaluate to an lvalue (though it shouldn't allow you to postincrement 0!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would appear to have a compiler bug, or perhaps a language extension, since this is not valid C.  You need an lvalue in order to apply the `++` operator, and `(c?c:0)` is not an lvalue.

Comment: why did it increase `c` if it was 0 before that line??? Undefined behavior imminent?

Comment: @unkulunkulu Since it is not valid C then arguing about why it outputs 1 rather than 0 or indeed anything else is somewhat moot.

Comment: would have been a nice comment, bad phrasing... since it's a compiler bug it might does "optimization" based on `(c?c:0) == c`

Comment: @unkulunkulu : the C99 standard does say explicitly : "If an attempt is made to modify the result of a conditional operator or to access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Sander: I don't think that sentence is relevant here.  The statement `(c?c:0)++;` violates a constraint, so even if the compiler accepts it (after printing the required diagnostic), the behavior is undefined anyway, since the conditional operator doesn't yield an lvalue.  That sentence must refer to some way of modifying the result of a conditional operator that *doesn't* involve a constraint violation.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way to do that.

Comment: @Keith : I also consider it quite redundant. It's possible that it's an artifact of an earlier draft where the conditional operator could return a modifiable lvalue. Nevertheless, having that phrase there pretty clearly addresses unkulunkulu's question without room for doubt, so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @Sander: No, it's not redundant.  I think it actually is possible to do this without violating a constraint, like this or something similar: `struct mystruct { int x; int a[2]; } r, s; (1 ? r : s).a[1] = 42;`.  Reference: Christian Bau, [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/f0d8751e95c4c677](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/f0d8751e95c4c677)

Comment: @Keith : interesting. Although the standard doesn't explicitly disallow that, I still think it should violate it, since the assignment operator needs a modifiable lvalue as the first operand, and the `.` operator yields "an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue.", which is not the case. It doesn't say that it could not yield a (modifiable) lvalue if the first expression is not an lvalue, but it probably should have. So, I stand corrected regarding my use of the word "redundant" - it should have been "poorly defined".

Comment: @Sander: That, or there's a better example that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run across some oddness related to this, too.  It seems that the result of a ternary conditional can be treated as an lvalue in gcc 3.3.2, but not in gcc 4.6 (I haven't got more versions ready to hand to narrow it down further).  In fact it's not possible to compile gcc 3.3.2 using gcc 4.6 precisely because gcc 4.6 is much pickier about what constitutes an lvalue.

Another example from the gcc 3.3.2 source that doesn't compile with gcc 4.6:

```
char *x = ...;
*((void**)x)++ = ...;
```

gcc 4.6 could treat the result of a cast as an lvalue and increment it, but gcc 4.6 will not.

I also don't have the relevant standards to hand to find out of this is something that changed in the official standard or just something that gcc allowed at some stage.

Note also that C++ allows the ternary operator to return an lvalue, though you still can't increment 0.  So this is valid C++ but not valid C:

```
int c = 0, d = 0;
(c?c:d)++;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply because you are doing

```
(c?c:0)++;
```

If you don't let "++" happen, you will get what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int c = 0;
  /*  (c?c:0)++;  */
  printf("%i \n", (c?c:0)++ );
  return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
$ gcc -o ternary ternary.c 
$ ./ternary 
0
```

`gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)`

Comment: That's not valid C either, you really mean `(c?c:0)+1` I presume

Comment: The way I understand is: `(c?c:0)++;` -- it will check if c exists. It does in this case (and in all cases here); it will do: `(value of c)++`. That gives 1. What is wrong in this?

Comment: The result of a ternary operator is not an lvalue

Comment: Thanks David. (if possible) can you please explain why is that a requirement? Just trying to understand why lvalue is a *must have* in this particular case.

Comment: @hari: ++ operates on a _modifiable lvalue_, else what would you expect it to update?

Comment: Because it's part of the language specification

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for responding. So what that means is, ternary operator can return a non-modifiable value?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks. I know that now. Being a developer, I am just trying to understand the rationale behind this *language specification*.

Comment: @hari Think about what 0++ could mean

Comment: @David Heffernan: Aah, that makes sense :) Thanks much.

Comment: @hari: no. the conditional expression yields something that is explicitly not a _lvalue_, though GCC _had_ an extension called _generalized lvalues_ that allowed using _compound expressions_ (_,_), _conditional expressions_ (_?:_) and _casts_ (_(type)_) as _lvalues_. You are probably seeing a remnant of that.